# how to get max geometric mean path for every two vertex in digraph

Tags: algorithm

I will illustrate my question through this example.
[image]
As the above **digraph**
as for the path form *A* to *C* denote (A,C),there exist three path:
`A->B->C`
  `A->C`
 `A->B->D->C`
and their geometric mean are:
`Math.pow(0.1*0.4,1/2)=0.2`
`Math.pow(0.4,1)=0.4`
`Math.pow(0.1*0.1*0.8,1/3)=0.2`
 Obviously, the max value is 0.4 that is to say the max geometric mean path is **A->C**

Then what I want to achieve is get **max geometric mean path** for every two vertex. My current method is use **DFS** to get all path for every two vertex and then compute **geometric mean value** every path and get max one.
**However** the number of vertex is more than 300 and the graphs is very complex. Then it will sacrifice too much much much time before getting results.

So I want to know it there exist more elegant algorithm to solve this question more quickly. I know **floyd algorithm** for Multi-source shortest path. But it seemed I cant use this algorithm to solve my question. I will appreciate for any advice , link or anything relevant.

Comment: Geometric Mean is a very unusual metric for path-selection.  In fact, *any* Mean is an odd metric for this.  What problem is this being applied to?  Perhaps there is a more natural approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the geometric mean is equal to (L_1 L_2 ... L_n)^(1/n), its natural logarithm is equal to 1/n * (log(L_1) + log(L_2) + ... + log(L_n). Since the log function is strictly monotonic, this means that path with the maximum geometric mean edge length condition is identical to the path with the maximum arithmetic mean log(edge length). So, the first simplification is to replace each edge length with its logarithm and reframe your condition as searching for the maximum arithmetic mean edge length. Naturally, any edge length equal to 0 should be removed, as a path including this edge can never have the maximum (unless every edge has 0 length). This rephrasing doesn't necessarily help that much, but it removes some artificial (i.e. apparent only at first glance) difficulty.

Next, the fact that you want the maximum mean edge length, rather than total edge length, must be dealt with. Among all paths of length n, the one with the maximum arithmetic mean edge length is the path with the maximum total length. So, choosing the path with the maximum mean edge length is equivalent to choosing the path with the maximum L_n / n, where L_n is the length of the maximum n-edge path. I haven't thought through the details, but it seems to me that it should be possible to compute L_n straight-forwardly (i.e. with as much difficulty as it takes to find the path with the maximum edge length overall, which is still NP hard), maybe with dynamic programming.

Comment: Little clarification. Path between two vertices incuding zero edge has the maximum geometric mean in case when all paths between this two vertices include edge with zero length, but not in case when all edges has zero length.